# Array of unique_ptr to Array of pointers

Tags: c++

Is array/vector of unique_ptr guaranteed to be array of raw pointers internally. It seems like it is so on my machine, but does the standard guarantee it?

I guess the question can be reduced to: Does unique_ptr always remain in memory as only a raw pointer or it's possible to have other metadata saved with it.

Basically i need to call a c function which takes an array of pointers (Actually it takes a double pointer obviously).
Now I can pass it a vector (vector::data) of unique_ptr with proper casting and it works fine. But I want to ensure that it will remain so on all the implementation of c++.

```
using item_ptr = unique_ptr<ITEM, ITEM_destructor>;
vector<item_ptr> items;
set_menu_items(m, reinterpret_cast<ITEM **>(items.data()));
```

Comment: Type punning in general is undefined behavior. Using it to access the underlying pointer type is asking for trouble. What is wrong with allocating a new vector and copying the raw pointers into it?

Comment: No, the behavior of your program is undefined.

Comment: @paddy These raw pointers have to be freed by calling a custom function. If I add them to vector directly I will have to manually free them in the end.

Comment: @paddy Okay you mean keep two vectors, one containing unique_ptr and other the raw ptrs. That would work. Thanks. Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never keep double administration and do not to use reinterpret_cast in your code!. There should only be one source of information. This one source will be your `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>`.
You only need a way to temporarily have a `Item**` to be able to pass this (as a view) to your `set_menu_items` call.

For this example I assume the list of items will NOT change after the call to `set_menu_items`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


// demo item
struct Item
{
    std::string name;
};

// function accepting only raw pointers
void set_menu_items(Item** items, const std::size_t number_of_items)
{
    for (std::size_t n{0ul}; n < number_of_items; ++n)
    {
        Item* item_ptr = items[n];
        std::cout << item_ptr->name << "\n";
    }
};

// a struct to hold raw pointers for a while
class temporary_item_pointers_t final
{
public:
    explicit temporary_item_pointers_t(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>>& item_ptrs)
    {
        for (const auto& ptr : item_ptrs)
        {
            m_item_ptrs.push_back(ptr.get());
        }
    }

    Item** get() noexcept
    {
        return m_item_ptrs.data();
    }

    auto size() const noexcept
    {
        return m_item_ptrs.size();
    }

private:
    std::vector<Item*> m_item_ptrs;
};


auto make_items(const std::vector<std::string>& names)
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item>> items;
    for (const auto& name : names)
    {
        items.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Item>(name));
    }
    return items;
}


int main()
{
    auto items = make_items({ "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" });
    temporary_item_pointers_t item_ptrs{ items };
    set_menu_items(item_ptrs.get(), item_ptrs.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I will make this the accepted answer. Although paddy said basically the same thing. He doesn't seem to be interested in making it an answer; and this **is** more informative and detailed.